# SpringBoot: EL1003E property values casting

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, properties-file, spring-el

I have a Spring Boot config file with this values:

```
@Value("#{new Integer('${db.pool.size}')}")
private Integer dbPoolSize;

@Value("#{new Integer('${db.minimum.idle}')}")
private Integer dbMinimumIdle;
```

But when I start the application I got this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1003E: A problem occurred whilst attempting to construct an object of type 'Integer' using arguments '(java.lang.String)'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.ConstructorReference.createNewInstance(ConstructorReference.java:168) ~[spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.ConstructorReference.getValueInternal(ConstructorReference.java:98) ~[spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120) ~[spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:242) ~[spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:161) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
@Value("${db.minimum.idle}")
private Integer dbMinimumIdle;
```

No need to explicitly instantiate new integer using spel.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have the following application.properties:

```
db.minimum.idle=12
db.pool.size=10
```

Then you should just do something like:

```
@Value("${db.pool.size}")
private Integer dbPoolSize;

@Value("${db.minimum.idle}")
private Integer dbMinimumIdle;
```

You do not have to create a new integer, that is automacally done by spring